# PayU Typescript types definition does not work in Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, payu

I'm trying to implement PayU payments in my project by following their documentation https://developers.payu.com/en/card_tokenization.html.
It says "If you use Typescript in your project, just add a types definition to your project."
So I did

> npm install --save @types/payu-emea-sdk

It also says "Add JS SDK script to every page you want to use Secure Form on".
Here I added https://secure.payu.com/javascript/sdk as script tag in my index.html file.
I also added types definition to tsconfig.json "compilerOptions"

> "types": [
> "node",
> "payu-emea-sdk"
> ]

Now when I try to use example

> var payu = PayU('393823');

compiler says "Cannot find name 'PayU'."

I was chatting with GPT for a couple of hours, but it gave up and sent me to support.
I asked support, but they don't have a working example of Secure Forms in Angular.
How can I use the provided type definitions in my project? Or, at least, how can I use the SDK without type definitions?